# Match data in SQL Server database using multiple and varying columns

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, algorithm

We have a database table consisting of 6 "header" criteria and we need to match any combination of these columns to retrieve the detail data.

We wont know which of the criteria the underlying database will have as each of the 8 header columns are optional.

Using example data :-

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----+---------+--------------+--------+
| First Name | Last Name | Home Town | Age |  Gender |    Skill     | Salary |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----+---------+--------------+--------+
| James      | Smith     | New York  | 30  | Male    | Train Driver |  30000 |
| Pete       | Jones     | ?         | 30  | Male    | ?            |  35000 |
| ?          | Smith     | New York  | ?   | Male    | ?            |  75000 |
| ?          | ?         | ?         | 30  | ?       | ?            |  30000 |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----+---------+--------------+--------+
```

When we want to find salary we might specify :-

```
First Name = James
Last Name = Smith
Home Town = New York
Age = 30
Gender = Male
Skill = Train Driver
```

Using this criteria we would expect to get the 1st, 3rd and 4th row returned.

Is there a slick way of doing this apart from iteratively working through the criteria with all the different combinations?!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi - I haven't, hence I am here asking.

Comment: SO strongly encourages you to try to find a solution on your own and help you along the way if you get stuck. How would you try to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: You have to atleast try something and show us code. If you don't try anything and you expect us to solve your problem. That's not gonna work here...

Comment: I am a very seasoned developer who has been pondering where to start on this for a while now.  I came here to draw on the knowledge of my peers for some guidance in a specific algorithm (hence the tags I used) and where the best place to get started would be.  If I already knew that I would not be here asking the question.

Comment: Do the question marks stand for NULL values? If so, then maybe `"... WHERE ([Field1] = @Field1Value OR [Field1] IS NULL) AND ([Field2] = @Field2Value OR [Field2] IS NULL) AND (...)"` might do want you want.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql I would use IFNULL() (I think there is an equivalent NVL() method in sql server)

E.g.

in your where query:

where IFNULL(row.FirstName, "James") == "James" and IFNULL(row.LastName, "Smith") and ..

Even better would be to use OR (i.e. check firstnames match or row.firstname is null)

Comment: Coraks answer may well work (SQL Server can use the "IS NULL" condition) but this has been one of those darn problems you stare at for ages thinking it's more complicated than it actually is!  Will ponder the IS NULL solution for a moment.  Thank you so much guys.

Comment: After initially playing around with the data I think this will solve it.  Damn I wasted a couple of days on this when the answer was so obvious - palm on forehead!  Again, many thanks for your help.